# UIControl derived class & need to call drawRect twice to draw correct control state

Tags: ios5, uikit

I have a class that inherits from UIControl that handles touchEvents and I don't understand why the 'setNeedsDisplay' method needs to invoked twice on touchEvents in order to have the correct state drawn in the UI. I've seen this pattern in a few examples where the various touches[Began|Ended] methods all invoke setNeedsDisplay directly and then once again with a delay using performSelector.

I can see what the result is when the 2nd setNeedsDisplay isn't invoked - the control is first rendered in the selected state but doesn't revert to normal state so the background remains as selected.

Why exactly does this behavior happen?

```
// a class that inherits from UIControl
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"drawRect, control state: %d", self.state);
    if (self.state == UIControlStateNormal)
    {
        [self setContentToNormalState];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        NSLog(@"Set background color: White");
    }
    else 
    {
        [self setContentToSelectedState];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        NSLog(@"Set background color: Grey");
    }

    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)hesitateUpdate
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

#pragma mark - Touch event handling

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self setHighlighted:YES];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self setHighlighted:NO];    
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
//    [self setNeedsDisplay];    
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    [self setHighlighted:NO];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [self performSelector:@selector(hesitateUpdate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self setHighlighted:NO];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    // Even with the following, if I tap and hold momentarily in the simulator, 
    // sometimes, the control has the gray background instead of white at the end
    [self performSelector:@selector(hesitateUpdate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];     
}
```